# "Allow HTML Temp" plugin set to Arabic for seemingly no reason

Tags: thunderbird, language, thunderbird-addon

I'm using the [Allow HTML Temp](https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/lexicon/entry/14-allow-html-temp/?l=2) plugin in Thunderbird 60.4.0 (on Manjaro Linux) and the Button and some of the menu texts from the plugin are displayed in Arabic since a couple of weeks. See screenshot as example:

[image]

Other than that, it works just as expected.

I've got no idea what causes this, as I'm neither using any Arabic locale on my machine, nor am I located in an Arabic speaking country.

output from `locale -a`:

```
C
de_AT.utf8
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here or how I can change this behavior?